# Get attribute from XML to PHP

Tags: php, xml

I read many guides about how to get information from XML file to php but still I can't do it. My XML file is from Lineage2 server. it consists:

```
    <npc id="25001" name="Greyclaw Kutus" title="Raid Boss">
    <set name="level" val="23"/>
    <set name="radius" val="21"/>
    <set name="height" val="43.5"/>
    <set name="rHand" val="67"/>
    <set name="lHand" val="633"/>
    <set name="type" val="L2RaidBoss"/>
    <set name="exp" val="714843"/>
    <set name="sp" val="67170"/>
    <set name="hp" val="40330.25972324"/>
    <set name="mp" val="231.96"/>
    <set name="hpRegen" val="17.5347470979605"/>
    <set name="mpRegen" val="1.5"/>
    <set name="pAtk" val="62.85327646485"/>
    <set name="pDef" val="286.94928"/>
    <set name="mAtk" val="3.96218033323786"/>
    <set name="mDef" val="139.98"/>
    <set name="crit" val="4"/>
    <set name="atkSpd" val="253"/>
    <set name="str" val="60"/>
    <set name="int" val="76"/>
    <set name="dex" val="73"/>
    <set name="wit" val="70"/>
    <set name="con" val="57"/>
    <set name="men" val="80"/>
    <set name="corpseTime" val="7"/>
    <set name="walkSpd" val="50"/>
    <set name="runSpd" val="170"/>
    <set name="dropHerbGroup" val="0"/>
    <ai type="DEFAULT" ssCount="0" ssRate="0" spsCount="0" spsRate="0" aggro="0" canMove="true" seedable="false"/>
    <skills>
        <skill id="4045" level="1"/>
        <skill id="4197" level="2"/>
        <skill id="4416" level="6"/>
        <skill id="4494" level="1"/>
        <skill id="4790" level="1"/>
    </skills>
    <drops>
        <category id="1">
            <drop itemid="69" min="1" max="1" chance="41197"/>
            <drop itemid="125" min="1" max="1" chance="41197"/>
            <drop itemid="126" min="1" max="1" chance="41197"/>
            <drop itemid="128" min="1" max="1" chance="41197"/>
        </category>
        <category id="2">
            <drop itemid="348" min="1" max="1" chance="166231"/>
            <drop itemid="377" min="1" max="1" chance="265410"/>
        </category>
        <category id="3">
            <drop itemid="956" min="12" max="36" chance="199025"/>
            <drop itemid="1935" min="53" max="157" chance="58816"/>
            <drop itemid="1937" min="24" max="72" chance="197852"/>
            <drop itemid="2021" min="3" max="9" chance="279149"/>
            <drop itemid="6575" min="1" max="1" chance="31844"/>
        </category>
        <category id="4">
            <drop itemid="6576" min="1" max="1" chance="286595"/>
        </category>
    </drops>
    <minions>
        <minion id="25002" min="3" max="3"/>
        <minion id="25003" min="1" max="1"/>
    </minions>
</npc>
```

I want to get name level and hp values when id=25001. how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleXMLElement for this, so something like this should work

```
$npc = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);

$values = array('hp', 'level');

if($npc->attributes()->id == '25001') {
    foreach($npc->set as $val) {
        if(in_array($val->attributes()->name, $values)) {
            var_dump($val->attributes()->val); 
            // whatever you want to do with it
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know for sure if this is the best solution but if you want some more information/documentation you can find it here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php